# Using pymc diagnostics and posterior summaries on samples not from pymc

Tags: python, mcmc, pymc

I'd like to use the pymc diagnostic and summary functions on samples I have generated without using pymc. As one example, I'd like to use pymc's mc_error routine on my own set of samples.

Some of the pymc diagnostic functions can take an np.array of samples, but, if I understand correctly, others seem to require a trace object. How can I convert my own set of samples into a trace object that pymc can handle? I'd appreciate any pointers.

My samples are currently stored as a dictionary where each key is a name of a variable I am sampling and points to an np.array of samples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about the `batchsd` function? That is what is used to calculate the MC error in PyMC 2. Its located in the `pymc.database.base` module, and can be used on any array, really.

The `pymc.diagnostics` module contains all the convergence diagnostics functions, and should work on numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! I was mistakenly looking at the mc_error function in stats.py in pymc, which I hadn't realised was decorated such that it first attempted to extract the trace array from whatever object it was passed. My original question was intended to be more general though: given that pymc has so many cool functions which work on traces, is there a canonical way of making a trace given your own samples without running mcmc in pymc?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, some of the PyMC* devs are spinning off a standalone package called [ArviZ](https://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/index.html) which includes functions for diagnosing and visualizing MCMC samples, etc.  It's still under heavy development as of Fall 2018, but they currently work with [xarray format](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/), an extension to pandas for working with tensor formatted data.